# Is fire immunity possible?

Tags: science-based, super-powers

So I have a character who is pyrokinetic. I already kinda have an answer to how his power actually works thanks to [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/how-can-i-expand-the-definition-and-some-specifics-of-pyrokinesis). Specifically the top answer

> you could have the user have the ability to emit intense heat out of their skin

So basically he "shoots" intense heat out of himself, igniting flammable objects or the air itself, giving the look of shooting flame.

But for this to work and not kill the person, he has to be immune to intense heat.

Is this possible in some way? Without a suit or any external sources?

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate, I'll check... Does this answer your question? 
 https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/184566/i-need-to-make-my-humanoid-able-to-resist-and-set-themselves-on-fire-with-at-lea

Comment: sorry no @DWKraus. That only answers for the concept of external heat, my character originates the intense heat from the inside.

Comment: @DWKraus Another point, the solutions still wouldn't work due to splashback. We are talking heat nearing 1000 degrees.

Comment: VTC:Opinion-Based. You want a [tag:science-based] explanation for how humans can have a super power? Really? Should we delete the answers that can't or don't cite a real-world example of a creature that utilizes their gene-spliced-into-humanity solution. There's a reason successful authors don't try to explain things like this.

Comment: I flagged this for deletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not possible without ignoring some things**

There are many creatures that are well insulated against heat, or have a great tolerance. Tardigrades can go up to 150°C (302F), Pompei worm up to 80C (176F) and desert ands 50C (122F). The thing is, those high temperatures aren't good for the Tardigrades and the Pompei worm is actually insulated against the heat, having one internal end of it's body at a more tolerable 22C (72F).

What this tells us is that high temperatures aren't healthy for life. Having the internal heat stored inside a body to ignite various objects with heat that looks like flames when thrown from the body seems too excessive. Even if it's only stored in the extremities, which generally are better in various heat conditions.

The "thowing" is also a problem. A lot of heat will not easily be "thrown" without stored in a medium. Like lightning, it'll obey certain rules. It'll likely expand and generally rise according to the environment.

Without further adaptation to the storage or a simple suspension of disbelief your pyrokinetic is in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't shoot towards yourself!**

A good principle generally!  For example, I have the inborn ability to produce a jet of water.  It is one of my powers, no joke.  Very early on I was trained to direct that jet away from myself and also away from persons and things I care about.  I was trained not to produce the jet when things like clothes or toys were in its path.  I am not immune to getting wet, but I have learned to control my power so as to minimize my chance of getting wet.

This is the same as your fire person!  Your fire person can shoot intense heat away from his own body, possibly in a manner very similar to my own water jet.  As with my jet of water, which if directed at an object too close might splash back on my khakis, your person directs his hot shootings such that they do not ignite your persons own stylish hair (containing great smelling but very flammable product!), flowing rayon scarf, or fuzzy panda socks.  Instead the heat travels until it intercepts a marshmallow, held at a safe distance on a green and fire-resistant stick.

The principle of "point it away" is an excellent and widely applicable one.

Comment: unfortunately, this isn't what I'm looking for. He generates the heat from the inside of himself and shoots it outward. Notice the keyword inside. I need my character to be immune inside and out.

Answer (score 1):

I think any science based answers are going to be difficult.

Scientists have found sharks among other creatures and plants living inside of active volcanoes, so there is some evidence for extreme heat resistance (including the breathing of the heated water through the gills, which is internal resistance, at least).

However, short of some sort of psychic ability to buff the body, full internal and external immunity is tough to find any sort of sciene-based evidence.

Maybe if we someday find living creatures in the sun or the earth's mantle or something?

Answer (score 0):

Heat asorbsion. The hotter it gets, the more comfortable it is for him, basically he is a living heat battery, you could even say he needs to vent heat every so often or he will "reach critical mass" and he will explode with heat blast like nuke.

Or leave it a mystery what would happen and he is warned to never get that much heat.